# how to get value from web browser control to windows form application Text Box?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

**I want to get the value of Dollar rate from web Browser to Windows Form Application Text Box !**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The [HtmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument) class provides tools to extract informations from `HTML` elements and grouping functions to aggregate elements that have common/specific attributes. See the [HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way, but this is not proper way to do but got little ideas.
First get the `WebView` content in string and then you can operate on hat string.

```
string str = webBrowser1.Document.ToString();
```

This may be or may not work.
You can also use cookies for that if you are opening your own URL.